# Autotask and DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

Has anyone out there created an API to kick off docusign from within the equote module in Autotask? 
I can't locate any references of autotask customers using docusign, nor docusign 'autotask' customers.

Comment: Yeah as Kim has pointed out, you should have no problem integrating DocuSign with Autotask.  Anywhere you have an application, or website, or some other system that can send http request you can integrate the DocuSign REST api or the SOAP api.

Answer (score 1):

From the DocuSign perspective, DocuSign can be integrated with any system that allows integration.  DocuSign offers both a REST API and a SOAP API, both of which enable you to add DocuSign eSignature transaction management functionality within the app being integrated. The DocuSign Developer Center contains a wealth of information about the DocuSign APIs (http://www.docusign.com/developer-center).

Since Autotask has an API that promotes "creating seemless integrations with leading...cloud- and managed-services tools" (http://www.autotask.com/main-pages/solutions/integrated-modules-features/open-api), I see no obvious reason that DocuSign couldn't be integrated with Autotask. i.e., provided that Autotask allows you to implement integration code that makes either REST API or SOAP API calls to another system, and use the API responses that you receive to subsequently implement the desired action(s) in Autotask (via their API), then integrating DocuSign with Autotask is certainly feasible.